# how to make vim to have python interactive runtime window

Tags: vim, python, vimrc

Is it possible to have python live program mode window open in python so we can call program and see the live outcome straightaway instead of jumpout vim to CMD?
It is a bit like VisualStudio setup.

Answer (score 2):

On Vim 8.*

**Basic option**

```
:w name-of-python-script.py    
:term python name-of-python-script.py    
:close
```

This will:
- save the script
- open a terminal within vim
- run the script and display the output
- close the terminal window
- return the cursor to the original window

**Another option is (using ipython):**

This will:
- open a vim terminal with ipython
- save the edit buffer as a python script (myscript.py)
- use :term_sendkeys() to send the ipython %run cmd to the :term window.

This example assumes the :terminal is buffer '2'

```
:call term_sendkeys(2, "%run myscript.py\<cr>")
```

The 'call term_sendkeys(..)' could be mapped to a key so running the script in the ipython buffer would be efficient.

```
:nnoremap <leader>zr :term_sendkeys(2, "%run myscript.py\<cr>")
```

**And another option is (using either python or ipython):**

This will:
- open a vim terminal with either python or ipython
- yank the edit buffer to a register (double-quote register in this example): `:%y"`
- send the buffer content to the python interpreter

```
:call term_sendkeys(2, @")
```

- Then map to a key for ease of use:

```
:nnoremap <leader>zk :%y \| :call term_sendkeys(2, @")<CR>
```